# VBA center TextBox

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to center text box in all slides like The picture please help me. I try this code but they're not work

```
Sub use2()
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.SlideMaster
With myDocument.Shapes(1)
    .TextFrame.HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
    .TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a `for-loop` incase you have multiples slides where the shape has to be centered. Make sure that the `Name` or `Index` of the shape is the same in all slides.

Edit: I misunderstood and assumed that OP wanted the text to be horizontally and vertically centered. They want the shape to be aligned to the center of the slide. I have edited the codes appropriately here:

```
Sub CenterTextBox()

For i = 1 to 10 'slidenumbers
On Error Resume Next
With ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("shapename")
   .Left = (ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth - .Width) / 2
   .Top = (ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight - .Height) / 2
End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please help me! there is an error and debugger point to .HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
The specified value is out of range.

Comment: Did you change `For i = 1 to 10` with the starting and ending slide numbers that contain the shape with the name `shapename`? Also, you can change the name of the shape via Selection Pane. Another solution would be to add `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: Instead of `Shapes("shapename")` you can also use `Shapes(1)`

Comment: You probably need to add this to the code you're running against the .TextFrame:  .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, I think OP wanted the shape to be aligned to the center and not the text. I have updated the code appropriately. Thank you~

Comment: @BhaveshShaha I think you're correct. But hey, in case they want the text box centered on the slide AND the text centered in the text box, we've got both bases covered now. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That will only work if the shape is on the master slide. If the shape is on a regular slide you need to reference that slide, by its index or id for example.

So

```
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
```

or

```
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides("name of slide")
```

Comment: We can also use `ActivePresentation.Slides(x)` where `x` is the Slide Number.